# How do I group similary items in an Android ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm building an app that lists items in a ListView.  There are a lot of items, and I'd like to present the user with a tree-like view that groups similar items (e.g. produce) under a parent category and expands to show the user the specific items (e.g. lettuce, tomato) after the user clicks on the category (e.g. produce).  Is the ListView the right view to use?  If so, how do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

[Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html) is an example on the Android Developer website.